# What could be the regex for matching combination of a specific string followed by number in a range?

Tags: javascript, regex

What could be the regex for matching a combination of a specific string followed by a number in a range?

For example

It should only match iOS8, iOS9, iOS10, iOS11, iOS12, iOS13

string - iOS |
range - 8 to 13

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression matches only those desired iOS versions listed:

```
iOS[89]|iOS[1][0-3]
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z8PBfy/1/)

#### Test

```js
const regex = /iOS[89]|iOS[1][0-3]/gm;
const str = `iOS7
iOS8
iOS9
iOS10
iOS11
iOS12
iOS13
iOS14`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

For iOS1 to iOS213, the following expression might for instance work, and we'd add start and end anchors, if we'd be validating:

```
^iOS[2][1][0-3]$|^iOS[2][0]\d$|^iOS[1][0-9][0-9]$|^iOS[1-9][0-9]$|^iOS[1-9]$
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/7mTMaS/1/)

```js
const regex = /^iOS[2][1][0-3]$|^iOS[2][0]\d$|^iOS[1][0-9][0-9]$|^iOS[1-9][0-9]$|^iOS[1-9]$/gm;
const str = `iOS0
iOS7
iOS8
iOS9
iOS10
iOS11
iOS12
iOS13
iOS14
iOS200
iOS201
iOS202
iOS203
iOS205
iOS214`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: More generic way

iOS[1][0-3]|iOS[1-9]

The range selection should be in the order as follows

3 digits, 2 digits, 1digit numbers

Eg: If the match is iOS1 to iOS 213

regex - iOS[1-2][0-1][0-3]|iOS[1][0-3]|iOS[1-9]

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to do the job is to extract the numeric value and compare with lowest value and highest value:

```js
var arr = ['iOS0','iOS1','iOS8','iOS12', 'iOS15', 'abc123']

console.log(arr.map(function (s) {
    if (m = s.match(/^iOS(\d+)$/)) {
        if (m[1] > 7 && m[1] < 14) {
            return s + " --> match";
        } else {
            return s + " --> no match";
        }
    } else {
        return s + " --> no match";
    }
}));
```